How a Debian package gets broken?
I've seen a lot of answers about how to fix a broken package in multiple distributions, which seems to be very helpful and solve the problems. But, I'm curious about how does a package get broken at all.
I was troubleshooting a pipeline which used an apt-get install command, and some dependency could not be installed. After some retries, I was able to make the pipeline work. But searching through solutions, I've found out that apt-get have a very useful --fix-broken flag, which solved my problem. But the question remains, what was the problem?  It isn't clear to me how to find the exact issue the --fix-broken solved to me.
Looking through its man page, there's some generic information about:
Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when
           used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely
           solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The
           option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not
           allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's
           dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention.

In the case of a pipeline, which its system is instantiated at the moment, what could've happened to the package that made it break? Does anyone get to go deeper on how this flags works? And most specifically, how a package gets broken?

The typical breakage that apt install --fix-broken addresses is missing dependencies. The usual way that happens is using dpkg to directly install a package: dpkg will know whether dependencies are missing, but it can’t retrieve missing dependencies, so the package will end up partially installed (installed but not configured). apt install --fix-broken resolves broken dependencies and installs any required packages — or removes utterly broken packages if their dependencies can’t be resolved.
If you are using dpkg directly, it’s typically better to use apt install — you can point it at a local package and it will resolve its dependencies during installation.

A package is just a piece of software with a list of dependencies. If your system has some non-standard installs (built from source, for example), or if you've pegged a specific version of a package (using "dpkg hold" or "dnf --exclude") to avoid breaking some other install, then trying to install a package that requires a different state of all of those dependent packages will fail, resulting in a "broken" package.
It's important to note there may be nothing wrong with the package or the state of your system. The original package may be fine with your hand-compiled (whatever), but since it's not what is expected it's seen as broken.

“Non-standard” installs aren’t known to the package manager, so they don’t affect it (unless they break a tool the package manager relies upon). When a resolving package manager (apt, dnf etc.) is used, it won’t install a package whose dependencies can’t be resolved, so it shouldn’t be possible to end up with a broken package using only those tools.
